# Wordpress baseurl

Tags: php, wordpress

I am buliding wordpress site for first time. I have dilema how to include files. I wanna make something  that will work in local and online. Is there in wordpress or PHP some Magic constant wich replace

`http://localhost/sitename` and could work when i upload site so domain should be

```
`http://www.sitename
```

I am currently been using

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/sitename/wp-config.php';`
```

Is this good way, of doing it? And is there better way, to create links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally with wordpress all use created files will be in the template directory, so use one of the built in functions like `get_template_directory()`

```
include_once(get_template_directory() . '/inc/somefile.php');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

There are a number of related functions for this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Alternatively, for the root directory you can use the constant `ABSPATH`:

```
echo ABSPATH;
```

Comment: hm this point me at theme directory, i am including files in my plugin script